# Check if listbox contains textbox

Tags: vb.net, string, textbox, listbox, contains

I know I could use `.FindString` for this but for some reason it is not working.

Basically,if listbox items contains just a PART of textbox text,it does action.

Here's the example of not-working code :

```
Dim x As Integer = -1
        x = ListBox1.FindString(TextBox1.Text)
        If x > -1 Then
            'dont add
            ListBox2.Items.Add("String found at " & x.ToString)
        Else

        End If
```

Comment: I hope that my answer was clear enough: you have to use `FindStringExact` instead of `FindString` to match the whole item. For example: if the ListBox contains "test1", "test"; if you use `FindString` with "test" (or "tes" or "te", etc.) it would return the first item. On the other hand, if you use `FindStringExact` also with "test", it would return the second item (and wouldn't find anything with "tes", "te", etc.).

Comment: @varocarbas It won't work if textbox contains 'foo.txt' and listbox contains 'C:\Users\foo.txt'.(I mean both .findstring and .findstringexact)

Comment: This is what I said in my answer: if you want more complex functionalities, you would have to interact through each element. In this case you would have to do a foreach loop through all the items and use `.Contains` for each of them (and `Exit For` when found). A foreach loop is really quick and shouldn't affect the performance. Bear in mind that `FindString` or `findstringexact` do precisely that (go through all the items). Next time, please describe the exact conditions you are after and I can write down a working code delivering the exact results you want (can do it now if you wish).

Comment: @varocarbas If it is not problem.I was trying .EndsWith (String list) but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FindString` method returns the first item which starts with the search string ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.findstring.aspx)). If you want to match the whole item, you would have to use `FindStringExact` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.findstringexact.aspx)). If you want to perform more complex searches, you would have to iterate through all the elements in the `ListBox`.

UPDATE:
Code delivering the exact functionality expected by the OP.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    If (ListBox1.Items(i).ToString.Contains(TextBox1.Text)) Then
        ListBox2.Items.Add("String found at " & (i + 1).ToString) 'Indexing is zero-based
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks,going to try it in a moment.EDIT:Works like a charm,thanks for your work.

Comment: @Jedi No problem. I guess that you want to output results starting from 1 (the indexing in my code starts from zero), that's why the `(i + 1).ToString`. Also you might want to consider `ToLower` in the comparison `ListBox1.Items(i).ToString.ToLower.Contains(TextBox1.Text.ToLower`) such that caps are ignored.

Comment: @Jedi I am happy to read that. Please, next time be as descriptive as possible (in your question but also by asking, requesting, etc.). I am here to help; but I cannot help if I don't know what you need.

Comment: wow thanks. I was looking for how to figure out how to get the text value of a listbox item for about three days. gave you an upvote!

Comment: @JTalati Thanks. Here comes a small piece of advice (if I may): the .NET Framework is very user friendly and the freely available documentation (MSDN) is very descriptive and has lots of sample codes. Using in-built functions (what is happening here) shouldn't ever be a problem, just do some tests by your own/understand better the controls you are working with via documentation. Knowing how to use the given programming language shouldn't ever be a problem (much less with the very-programming-friendly .NET Framework), the difficulty is applying it right to solve whatever needs to be solved.